# Wordpress - Grant Role Menus and Widgets

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress configuration where I would like to allow a user to edit Menus and Widgets without exposing the Theme and Edit CSS options.

Can anyone point out how to do this? So far I have only been able to expose all of the "Appearance" menu in the dashboard to that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few WP Capabilities that are used to control access to the themes appearance menu.

**"edit_theme_options"** - use to allow access to the widgets, menus and theme options, and to deny access to switch themes, or modify files in the theme.

```
$role = get_role( 'editor' );
$role->add_cap( 'edit_theme_options' );
```

**"switch_themes"** - allows access to switch themes.

**edit_themes** - allows to edit files in the theme.

NOTE: Because `add_cap` function saves settings in the database, they will stay until are removed with `remove_cap` function.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with the plugin [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/).  It gives you the ability to control who sees what for every option in the admin menu and a lot more.  It is very detailed and can be a little overwhelming at first, but it isn't as bad as it looks once you've spent a little time around it.  Hope that helps and good luck.